# Multiple aggregations based on combination Id and Date (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and stackoverflow so i will try my best to explain what my problem is.

I have a dataframe as the below and i would like to aggregate rows with same Customer Id and Date (so each Customer id-Date combination only needs to repeat ones) using multiple logics:

- Sum of quantity for that date-customer id (how many pieces in total the customer bought each purchase day date)
- Count of Sales id for that date-customer id (how many sales order the customer placed each purchase day)
- distinct count of shop id for that date-customer id (from how many shops the customer placed orders each purchase day)
- Last we have in the product category 2 products only that i identified as 0 or 1, I would like to add 2 columns that count number of sales orders of product category 0 and count number of sales orders of product category 1.

I tried using the below code to solve the first 3 points but without success.

df = df.groupby('customer id','date').sum('Quantity').count('Sales id').nunique('Shop id')

Really struggling with the last fourth point.

Hope you can help me out here.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kHhQ.png)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDcCI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of the first 3 points using agg() method:

df.groupby(['Customer id','Date'],as_index=False).agg({'Quantity' : ['sum'], 'Sale id' : ['count'], 'shop id' : ['nunique']})

Ideally I would add within agg() two additional aggregations to that count 'Product category' when == '0' and when =='1'
Any ideas?